# Relacionamento manytomany entre três tabelas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
Action
-id
-name
-type

Routes
-id
-name
-controllers

User
-id
-name
-email
-password
-usergroup_id

Usergroup
-id
-name
-tenant_id
```

Eu quero fazer uma relação onde eu consiga saber quais ações em uma rota especifica o usuário pode fazer, e a mesma coisa para o grupo de usuário, pois se o usuário não tiver a ação então será validado as ações do grupo dele.

Neste caso eu teria que criar duas tabelas pivot?:

```
Action_Routes_User
-action_id
-route_id
-user_id

Action_Routes_Usergroup
-action_id
-route_id
-usergroup_id
```

e passar belongsToMany em tudo, certo?

eu consegui fazer essa relação, mas para conseguir quais ações X usuário tem em determinada rota que da problema:

```
//model User
public function routes()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Route::class, 'action_route_user', 'user_id', 'route_id');
}

//model Route
public function actionsUser()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class, 'action_route_user', 'route_id', 'action_id');
}
```

quando faço $user->routes obtenho todas as rotas relacionadas a este usuário, ai ok...

mas quando pego uma rota dessa coleção acima por exemplo:

```
$routes = $user->routes;
foreach($routes as $route) {
$routeActions = $route->actionsUser;

// aqui ele está pegando todas as ações independente do usuário ID
// tipo , do usuário que estou logado: Iury pego as rotas que ele tem permissão iury->routes , ai tudo certo
// mas quando pego uma das rotas: $route->actionsUser é como se ele tivesse buscando todas as ações dos usuários nessa tabela pivot action_route_user e não só do iury
}
```

creio que está faltando um where user_id quando for buscar nessa tabela de pivot, se sim qual melhor jeito de por?

Comment: Podes tentar: `$route->actionsUser()->where('action_route_user.user_id', $user->id)->get();`

Comment: eu coloquei outra função dentro do model User chamada actionsUserWhere que faz justamente isso porém com o id do route já que está dentro do model User, da no mesmo né?

Comment: Sim, mas talvez estejas a fazer mais chamadas à BD do é suposto, mais vale entrar logo o id do user talvez

Comment: Primeiramente, bem vindo! Segundamente, reveja sua lógica. Você recupera uma route, e depois itera sobre ele, em busca de actions, ele vai retornar todas as relações. Interessante seria ter uma relação direta entre o user e as actions

Comment: Obrigado Flavio, bom, eu criei uma ligacao direta do user para actions, e acrescentei um where, route_id 

`public function actionsWhere($routeId)
    { return $this->belongsToMany(Action::class, 'action_route_user', 'user_id','action_id')->withPivot('route_id') ->wherePivot('route_id', $routeId)->get();}`

assim deu certo! trouxe todas as ações relacionadas a rota do id colocado, assim eu consegui validar no **gate** e não deixar fazer uma ação que o usuário não tenha permissão, seria essa a logica que você falou?

Comment: Acho que você poderia melhorar sua modelagem acabando com a tabela action e passando direto na routes isso deixaria o sistema mais flexível e menos pesado em questão de banco